# Add a custom column to a table created from a ModelForm

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms

So I would like to add an extra column to each row of a table generated from a ModelForm. Within the Django template, I use:

```
 {{form.as_table}}
```

Depending of the row, the content of that column will be different. Right now I have this:

```
$('.table tr').each(function() {
    $(this).append("<td></td>");        
})
var row = $("#id_manufacturer").parent().parent();
var cells = $("td", test);
$(cells[1]).append("Stuff I am adding for this specific row");
```

Do we have a better way to do this!? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the only content you need to add, then that should be fine.

You could refine the code slightly as follows :

```
$('.table tr').each(function() {
    $(this).append('<td class="myNewColumn"></td>');
})
$("#id_manufacturer").closest("tr").find("td.myNewColumn").append("Stuff I am adding for this specific row");
```

*I'm not sure about `test` but assume you meant `row`.*

This approach avoids `.parent().parent()`, which is a bit ugly and prone to error if the HTML structure alters in the future.

Similarly, a classname to identify the newly added column immunises you from future changes to the table structure. `cells[1]` might one day become `cells[2]` for example.

Essentially, my code is doing exactly the same as your original, plus a bit of future-proofing.